# Output JavaScript from Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. One of the views in my app has some JavaScript. I want to set the value of a JavaScript variable based on a value in the ViewBag. If the ViewBag value exists and is not null, I want to use it. Otherwise, I want to assign an empty string value to the JavaScript variable. Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function formatItem(item) {
    var itemName = @(ViewBag.ItemName ? ViewBag.ItemName : '');
    alert(itemName);
  }
</script>
```

This block throws an error that says:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1011: Empty character literal
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Don't forget that Razor will escape all strings. If you want to prevent that and you're 100% sure there's noting evil in that string you can use `@Html.Raw()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use an empty string instead of a character literal (double quotes versus single quotes):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function formatItem(item) {
    var itemName = '@((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ItemName)) ? ViewBag.ItemName : "")';
    alert(itemName);
}
</script>
```

Your only real problem was that you used '' instead of "". '' Means a character, "" means a string;

Answer (score 3):

You need double quotes and not single quotes.

```
var itemName = '@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ItemName) ? ViewBag.ItemName : "")';
```

even better you might want to use the `String` object:

```
var itemName = '@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ItemName) ? ViewBag.ItemName : String.Empty)';
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript. `ViewBag.ItemName` is not boolean. He needs to use something like `??` or `string.IsNullOrEmpty`